# trigger insert na mesma tabela

Tags: sql, postgresql, funções, trigger, sql-insert

Olá, tenho uma tabela onde guardo registros de movimentações, nela é inserido um registro onde é possível informar uma parcela de pagamento, por exemplo, uma compra feita em 12 vezes cuja parcela atual (a que foi inserida manualmente no banco) seja a parcela **8/12**, faltando ainda 4 parcelas, deste modo ao inserir este registro a trigger deverá inserir os registros das parcelas 9, 10, 11 e 12, todos os demais dados devem ser os mesmos, sendo apenas o número da parcela diferente, segue o código que fiz:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_parcelas_futuras()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF NEW.quantidade_parcelas > 1 THEN
        FOR mes_parcela IN NEW.parcela_atual..NEW.quantidade_parcelas LOOP
            INSERT INTO movimentacoes(
                operacao,
                nome_operacao,
                id_estabelecimento,
                id_cartao,
                parcela_atual,
                quantidade_parcelas,
                valor_parcela,
                mes_fatura
            )
                VALUES(
                    NEW.operacao,
                    NEW.nome_operacao,
                    NEW.id_estabelecimento,
                    NEW.id_cartao,
                    mes_parcela,
                    NEW.quantidade_parcelas,
                    NEW.valor_parcela,
                    NEW.mes_fatura
                );
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER tg_inserir_parcelas_futuras
AFTER INSERT
ON movimentacoes
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_parcelas_futuras();
```

Quando tento inserir algum dado recebo o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT 1 FROM ONLY "public"."cartoes" x WHERE "codigo" OPERATOR(pg_catalog.=) $1 FOR KEY SHARE OF x"
SQL statement "INSERT INTO movimentacoes(
                operacao,
                nome_operacao,
                id_estabelecimento,
                id_cartao,
                parcela_atual,
                quantidade_parcelas,
                valor_parcela,
                mes_fatura
            )
                VALUES(
                    NEW.operacao,
                    NEW.nome_operacao,
                    NEW.id_estabelecimento,
                    NEW.id_cartao,
                    mes_parcela,
                    NEW.quantidade_parcelas,
                    NEW.valor_parcela,
                    NEW.mes_fatura
                )"
PL/pgSQL function fn_parcelas_futuras() line 5 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO movimentacoes(
                operacao,
                nome_operacao,
                id_estabelecimento,
                id_cartao,
                parcela_atual,
                quantidade_parcelas,
                valor_parcela,
                mes_fatura
            )
                VALUES(
                    NEW.operacao,
                    NEW.nome_operacao,
                    NEW.id_estabelecimento,
                    NEW.id_cartao,
                    mes_parcela,
                    NEW.quantidade_parcelas,
                    NEW.valor_parcela,
                    NEW.mes_fatura
                )"
[...]
REPETE ULTIMO BLOCO ALGUMAS VEZES.
[...]

PL/pgSQL function fn_parcelas_futuras() line 5 at SQL statement
SQL state: 54001
```

Comment: *"a trigger deverá inserir os registros das parcelas 9, 10, 11 e 12"* a trigger não tem bem esse propósito, você precisa fazer uma `procedure` que é o objeto mais correto para fazer esse tipo de operação

Comment: Certo, no caso a `trigger` deveria chamar a `procedure` então, é isso?

Comment: A trigger fica recursiva (stack depth limit exceeded) , mas esta lógica não está fazendo sentido , o que inseriu a "8" ?! Um processo deve inserir dacparcela 1 até a "n".

Comment: @bruno101 seria melhor por todo o código na procedure sem trigger, faz todos os inserts em "movimentacoes" numa única procedure, claro e bem definidio, inclusive pode ser transacional, fazer o commit ao gerar todas as parcelas, não precisa de um trigger

Comment: @Motta eu mencionei ali, a parcela 8 teria sido inserida manualmente, então o próprio banco deveria inserir as demais parcelas restantes, caso tivesse sido inserida a parcela 1/12 todas as demais deveriam ser inseridas, caso fosse a 12/12 nada seria feito, pois já é a última parcela.

Comment: @RicardoPontual mas a `procedure` não necessitaria de uma `trigger` para ser chamada? Mesmo que todo o processo seja feito na `procedure`.

Comment: O problema é a trigger fica recursiva , vai inserir por exemplo da 8 a 12 , ao inserir a 8 a trigger insere na tabela e se dispara da 9 a 12 e assim por diante , a trigger não parece caber aqui neste caso.

Comment: @bruno101 *"a procedure não necessitaria de uma trigger para ser chamada"* claro que não, se fosse assim, pra toda procedure precisaria de uma trigger :) no lugar de executar um `insert` executa o procedure que vai fazer todos os inserts de uma vez, vai mudar só isso no jeito de fazer a chamada

Comment: @Motta entendi o que tu quis dizer, de fato, da chamada 9 até a 12 teríamos `triggers` sendo disparadas consequentemente a cada novo `insert`, de fato não é esse o comportamento desejado.

Comment: @RicardoPontual neste caso eu faria uma `procedure` para inserir dados, esta seria responsável de avaliar a situação e necessidade de inserção dos demais dados. Seria isso? Algo como: `pr_insert_movimentacoes(<parâmetros do insert aqui>)`

Comment: extamente isso, ai pode controlar tudo numa mesma procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme indicações de @RicardoPontual e @Motta, a solução que estava desenvolvendo não daria certo, pois acabaria caindo em uma recursão da execução da `query`, foi indicado a resolução por meio de uma `procedure` onde apenas faria a chamada da mesma, não sei se a execução foi a melhor, acredito que dê para melhorar, mas segue o código desenvolvido.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PR_INSERT_MOVIMENTACOES(
    operacao bool,
    nome_operacao VARCHAR(255),
    id_estabelecimento INTEGER,
    id_cartao INTEGER,
    parcela_atual INTEGER,
    quantidade_parcelas INTEGER,
    valor_parcela NUMERIC(12,2),
    mes_fatura INTEGER
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
    mes_fatura_parcela INTEGER := mes_fatura;
BEGIN
    IF parcela_atual < quantidade_parcelas THEN
        FOR mes_parcela IN parcela_atual..quantidade_parcelas LOOP
            INSERT INTO movimentacoes(
                operacao,
                nome_operacao,
                id_estabelecimento,
                id_cartao,
                parcela_atual,
                quantidade_parcelas,
                valor_parcela,
                mes_fatura)
            VALUES(
                operacao,
                nome_operacao,
                id_estabelecimento,
                id_cartao,
                mes_parcela,
                quantidade_parcelas,
                valor_parcela,
                mes_fatura_parcela);

            mes_fatura_parcela := mes_fatura_parcela + 1;

            IF mes_fatura_parcela > 12 THEN
                mes_fatura_parcela := 1;
            END IF;
            
        END LOOP;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO movimentacoes(
                operacao,
                nome_operacao,
                id_estabelecimento,
                id_cartao,
                parcela_atual,
                quantidade_parcelas,
                valor_parcela,
                mes_fatura)
            VALUES(
                operacao,
                nome_operacao,
                id_estabelecimento,
                id_cartao,
                parcela_atual,
                quantidade_parcelas,
                valor_parcela,
                mes_fatura);
    END IF;
    
    COMMIT;
END;$$
```

Com isto basta fazer a seguinte chamada:

```
CALL PR_INSERT_MOVIMENTACOES(false, 'Produto teste', 1, 3, 5, 7, 20.55, 4);
```

De modo que agora a `procedure` insere os registros das parcelas 6 e 7 de forma automática e também atualiza o mês da fatura para 5 e 6 respectivamente.